# Google calendar api update is not changing event information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm using a google service account in my web app to create and update google calendars. When I send a request to update an event with (for example) a new set of dates it's coming back with all of the correct information, but the event isn't changing at all on my calendar.

I read that incrementing the sequence could fix the issue, but when I try that I get a 403 error back from google.

Here is some of my code:

```
var service = AuthenticateServiceAccount.NewCalendarService();

Event CalendarEvent = service.Events.Get(GooglePrimaryEmail, GoogleCalendarEventID).Execute();

string StartTime = Request.StartDate;

string EndTime = Request.EndDate;

Event GoogleEvent = service.Events.Update(CalendarEvent, GooglePrimaryEmail, GoogleCalendarEventID).Execute();
```

When I look at the GoogleEvent object all of the fields are updated just like I want it to be, but there are no updates to my calendar. I have no issues creating or deleting calendar events, so I know that my service is set up correctly.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you using impersonation for your service account or are you using personal gmail address to update the event? If you are using personal address, then your personal calendar gets updated. Also, in the code here service.Events.Update you are not sending the startTime and EndTIme values. Try changing that. you can also test your scenario here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update. I tried to update event in my calendar and its working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using a 'dev' gmail account as a service account to make the updates. So the dev account is the one making the changes to the events, but the calendar is whoever I specify in my program. In my actual code I am sending in the start and end times, I just tried to compress it here and forgot a line. I finally just got tired of trying to figure it out and went another route.